Why can't I assign the reference to a field in the same ref struct to a ref field?
Given this mostly contrived example:
ref struct RefStruct {
    int _field;
    ref int _refField;

    void AssignRef() {
        _refField = ref _field;
        // CS8374 Cannot ref-assign '_field' to '_refField' because '_field' has a narrower escape scope than '_refField'.
    }
}

The docs state that:

The compiler ensures that a reference stored in a ref field doesn't
outlive its referent.

But in what circumstances will the reference to the private _field stored in _refField going to outlive the referent?

ref int evilVar = anInstanceOfStruct._refField; seems like it could escape like that.

A non-ref field lives as long as the struct instance lives, but a ref field can live for as long as the caller wants.
In more accurate terms, normal fields have the ref-safe-context of "function member", but ref fields have the ref-safe-context of "caller context". See the rules here for more details.
To demonstrate how _refField can outlive _field, you can do this:
// in RefStruct...
public static ref int Foo() {
    var s = new RefStruct();
    return ref s._refField;
    // the lifetime of s ends here! But _refField is still living!
}

Then Foo can be called like this:
ref int foo = ref RefStruct.Foo();

If you were able to do _refField = ref _field;, foo here would be referring to a _field field of a RefStruct instance that is already "dead".

Thanks for the example. Specs are as obvious when you know the answer as always.
